# Bootstrap 4 - empty row (initially) needs to have a height

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have this style:

```
    #cytoscape-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        /*border: 1px solid red;*/
    }

    .cytoscape-parent {
        height: 800px;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

That goes with this HTML:

```
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="displayAll()">Draw All</button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="clearAll()">Clear</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-xs-12 cytoscape-parent" >
            <div class="w-100 h-100 d-inline-block" id="cytoscape-container"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The second row gets a Cytoscape js graph drawn into it when a button is clicked.  However, if I don't set the `.cytoscape-parent` height to something like `height: xxxpx;` The row height is always 1 and my diagram does not get drawn.  How can I set it to a percentage of the browser window height (like 90%)?

The `#cytoscape-container` size is 100% of whatever the `.cytoscape-parent` is, which is what I want, but I want to set the parent as a %age of the browser window height...

Comment: can you use `vh` in your CSS code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function displayAll() {}
function clearAll() {}
```

```css
#cytoscape-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: yellow;
}

.cytoscape-parent {
  height: 80vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="displayAll()">Draw All</button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="clearAll()">Clear</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 cytoscape-parent">
      <div class="w-100 h-100 d-inline-block" id="cytoscape-container"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```